# Migration from Weblogic to Apache Tomcat in SpringBoot 2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, weblogic

I am migrating an application from weblogic platform to Spring Boot 2.0 using embedded Tomcat Server. Do I need to convert weblogic.xml to some Java level configuration/code and if yes please advise on how should we do that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
       <wls:context-root>myProject</wls:context-root>

    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.apache.xerces.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.*</wls:package-name> 
        <!--    <wls:package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</wls:package-name> -->
                <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
 <wls:session-descriptor>
    <wls:url-rewriting-enabled>true</wls:url-rewriting-enabled>
    <wls:id-length>52</wls:id-length>
    <wls:cookie-comment>WebLogic Server Session Tracking Cookie</wls:cookie-comment>
    <wls:cookie-max-age-secs>-1</wls:cookie-max-age-secs>
    <wls:cookie-name>projectuser</wls:cookie-name>
    <wls:invalidation-interval-secs>60</wls:invalidation-interval-secs>    
    <cookies-enabled>true</cookies-enabled>
    <wls:cookie-http-only>true</wls:cookie-http-only>
   <!--  <wls:cookie-secure>true</wls:cookie-secure> -->
    <tracking-enabled>true</tracking-enabled>
    <timeout-secs>3600</timeout-secs>
 </wls:session-descriptor>

</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: Actually it is easy, just create a Spring boot 2.0 application and copy your business code on that.

Comment: Could you elaborate on copying business code

Comment: Business code is your own implementation. I meant you do not need change any weblogic file. In your Spring Boot application it wont be used.